# Sufficient condition placed on $f(x,y)$ to obtain isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $k[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials in $x,y$ with coefficients in $k$.

Let $\mathcal{O}(W) := k[x,y]/\langle f(x,y) \rangle$, where $f(x,y)$ is the irreducible quadratic in two variables $f(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + g$.

My question is, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions we need to place on $f$ such that $\mathcal{O}(W) \cong k[x]$?

My guess is that we need to remove the cross term, so it is simply the case of setting $c=0$, since we have a simple relationship between getting $y$ from elements in $k$ and $x$.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean an abstract isomorphism, do you? You better write $\mathcal O(W) \cong k[t]$ then.

Comment: Is your field algebraically closed? Characteristic zero?

Comment: Letting $c=0$ is not enough, even in the algebraically closed case. Note that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is not isomorphic to a polynomial ring, because $(x+iy)$ and $(x-iy)$ are units, but their sum $2x$ is not a unit, because $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1,2x)=\mathbb C[y]/(y^2-1) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $k = \overline k$ and $k$ is of characteristic zero.

I will try to answer geometrically. Let $W$ be the zero set of your polynomial, and let's look in $\Bbb P^2$ and $X = \overline W$. We know that $W = X \backslash \{p_1, p_2\}$ for some points $p_1, p_2$ (not necessary distinct).

Now, we now that a smooth conic is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$. It follows that if $p_1, p_2$ are distincts one has $Y \cong k^*$ and so $\mathcal O(W) = k[t,t^{-1}]$. This is given e.g by $f(x,y) = xy - 1$. If $p_1 = p_2$ then it follows that $W \cong \Bbb A^1$ so $\mathcal O(W) \cong k[t]$ as expected. In particular, you also have to check that your curve is smooth, else you will have $\mathcal O(W) \cong k[t] \times k[s]$ or $\mathcal O(W) \cong k[x,y)]/(xy)$ or  as shows the polynomial $f(x,y) = y(x-1)$, resp $f(x,y) = xy$ (depending if the singular point is on the line at infinity or not).

In maybe more algebraic terms, parametrizing the line at infinity $L$ will gives you a polynomial $g = f_{|L}$ of degree $2$, in one variable. The condition that $L$ is tangent at $X$ is exactly the condition that polynomial $g$ has a double root.

Comment: You make assumption on $k$ that the OP has never said anything of. At least state that you makes these assumptions.

Comment: @MooS : you are right, I am used to always work with $\Bbb C$. I'll edit my answer, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Of course it is pretty reasonable to make these assumptions and probably the OP assumed them without saying.

Comment: @Moos exactly, I usually assume $k=\mathbb{C}$ but the text Im working in uses $k$ as an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (Hartshorne). Sorry for the confusion.